# Javascript not showing

Tags: javascript, html, forms, innerhtml

I'm new to JavaScript. I created this html form that calls a JS function. The function should make a simple calculation and return the total value to the HTML using innerHTML but for some reason it's not working. 
Can somebody please help to find what is wrong with it? Tks!

```
<form id="inputInfo" name="inputInfo">

    <span> Insert a value </span><br/>
    <input type="number" id="value"> <br/>
    <button id="send" type="submit" class="button" onclick="calculate()">  <span> Send </span></button>

    <!--output from javascript-->
    <p id="output1"> </p>
    <p id="output2"> </p>
    <p id="output3"> </p>

</form>

  //** Function below is into a .js file **//

function calculate() {

var value = document.getElementById("value");
var commission;
var finalValue;
var message;

if(value <= 0){
    commission = 0;
    finalValue = 0;
    message = "* Value is wrong! *";

} else {
    commission = value < 250 ? 25 : (value * 0.1);
    finalValue = value + commission;
    message = "";

    }

document.getElementById("output1").value.innerHTML = finalValue;
document.getElementById("output2").value.innerHTML = commission;
document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = message;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `var value = document.getElementById("value");`, you are only accessing the DOM of the input. You will need to do `.value` in order to actually get the "value" of the input:

`var value = document.getElementById("value").value;`

As for the output parts:

`document.getElementById("output1").value.innerHTML = finalValue;`
`document.getElementById("output2").value.innerHTML = commission;`
`document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = message;`

Remove the `.value` and only use `.innerHTML` for these.

As with above, you are accessing the DIM with `document.getElementById("output1")`, and you set the `innerHTML` value.

Full code sample: https://jsfiddle.net/u87a7e6b/

```
<form id="inputInfo" name="inputInfo">

  <span> Insert a value </span>
  <br/>
  <input type="number" id="value">
  <br/>
  <button id="send" type="button" class="button" onclick="calculate()"> <span> Send </span></button>

  <!--output from javascript-->
  <p id="output1"> </p>
  <p id="output2"> </p>
  <p id="output3"> </p>

</form>

<script>
function calculate() {
  var value = document.getElementById("value").value;
  var commission;
  var finalValue;
  var message;

  if (value <= 0) {
    commission = 0;
    finalValue = 0;
    message = "* Value is wrong! *";

  } else {
    commission = value < 250 ? 25 : (value * 0.1);
    finalValue = value + commission;
    message = "";
  }

  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = finalValue;
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = commission;
  document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = message;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I added but still not working. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Updated to reflect some errors in the output section.

Comment: With this updates I'm able to see the results for 1 sec and then it disappears from the browser. =|

Comment: Updated with full code samples :)

In the HTML, your button needs to be `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` to prevent the form from submitting. It disappears from the browser because the browser tries to submit the form and causes a page reload.

Comment: In the HTML, your button needs to be type="button" instead of type="submit" to prevent the form from submitting. It disappears from the browser because the browser tries to submit the form and causes a page reload.

Comment: Got it! Excellent! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a line:

```
value = parseInt(value);
```

Otherwise JavaScript may treat the "value" as a type of string.

Here is the full code

```js
function calculate() {
  var value = document.getElementById("value").value;

  value = parseInt(value);
  var commission;
  var finalValue;
  var message;

  if (value <= 0) {
    commission = 0;
    finalValue = 0;
    message = "* Value is wrong! *";

  } else {
    commission = value < 250 ? 25 : (value * 0.1);
    finalValue = value + commission;
    message = "";
  }

  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = finalValue;
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = commission;
  document.getElementById("output3").innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<form id="inputInfo" name="inputInfo">

  <span> Insert a value </span>
  <br>
  <input type="number" id="value">
  <br>
  <button id="send" type="button" class="button" onclick="calculate()"> <span> Send </span></button>

  <!--output from javascript-->
  <p id="output1"> </p>
  <p id="output2"> </p>
  <p id="output3"> </p>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that after correcting DOM access, the variable `value` contains the string value of text entered into the input element. It needs to be converted into a number for addition to add numbers together instead of concatenating them as strings. One solution is to replace the line

```
    if (value <= 0) {
```

with these two

```
    value = parseFloat( value);
    if( value <= 0 || isNaN(value) {
```

Comment: Ok, I'll do that.. Thank you!